# Две одинаковые формы (form) на одной странице сайта.. Нижняя не отправляет данные

Tags: javascript, php, html, form

Ребята, помогите разобраться с формами. Две одинаковые формы, на одной странице. Верхняя, в верху страницы - работает, коряво но работает. Нижняя,  в низу страницы, имеет полностью такой же код как верхняя, не отправляет данные - Заполните все поля, всплывает окно.
Код формы:

```
<form id="recallForm" method="post" action="/mail/recallmail.php">
<input class="recallInput" type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
<input class="recallInput" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="8 (___) ___ - __ -__" maxlength="15" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="Замена ручек">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Отправить!" onclick="recall()">
</form>
```

Я плохо разбираюсь в php и  скриптах. Мне её установил знакомый один и пропал. Пытаюсь разобраться, понять миниум.который нужен. На этой же странице присутствует скрипт.
Вот его код:

```
<script>
function recall(){
$.post("/mail/recallmail.php",$("#recallForm").serialize(),function ( data ){
$(".recallInput").val("");
window.location.hash="sensorReplacement";
alert(data);
});
};
</script>
```

Я примерно понимаю что надо изменить id в нижней форме. Или добавить id  к полям ввода данных.... ID  у формы есть, я нижней форме  присвою  уникальный id. А как его добавить в код скрипта?
Для понимания, вот код нижний формы. Я сразу изменил id.

```
<form id="otherrepairForm" method="post" action="/mail/recallmail.php">
<input class="recallInput" type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
<input class="recallInput" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="8 (___) ___ - __ -__" maxlength="15" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="Замена ручек">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Отправить!" onclick="recall()">
</form>
```

Как изменить скрипт? Прописать отдельную функцию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Отправить!" onclick="recall(this)">

function recall(btn) {
  var $form = $(btn).closest("form"); 
  $.post("/mail/recallmail.php", $form.serialize(), function(data) {
    $form.find(".recallInput").val("");
    window.location.hash = "sensorReplacement";
    alert(data);
  });
};
```

Comment: <input type="button" class="btn" value="Отправить!" onclick="recall(this)">.  Это код для кнопки в форме. Я понял. А  в обе формы его вставлять?

Comment: @ДенисКартинкин Да, в обе формы.

Comment: А id форм делать разным?  А.... Ну да. Это же id. Думаю идентификатор не должен повторяться в коде одного файла.      А зачем тогда id в form?  Предполагаю id прописан в файле recallmail.php.

Comment: @ДенисКартинкин Низачем. `id` в формах не нужен.

Comment: Был еще такой момент, меня он беспокоил. Заполнив, верхнюю - рабочую форму,  менялся адрес страницы. К адресу добавлялся... Ну вот пример - https://мойсайт.ру/datchik-zamena.html#sensorReplacementчто . Это нормально? Я думаю нет. Как это исправить? Спасибо что .уделили время. Буду применять на сайте. Обязательно сообщу о результатах.

Comment: @ДенисКартинкин "Как это исправить?" - Удалить строчку `window.location.hash = "sensorReplacement";`.